# Bootstrap 3 Panel footer

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a panel on my page but applied the .Well class to the body of it so give it a background rather than plain white.

There is now a white gap on the bottom. Any idea how I can remove that ?

[image]

```
 <div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
     <h3 class="panel-title">Attendee Information</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body well">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
         <label>Required</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="requiredAttendees" placeholder="Please select required attendee's">
           <p class="help-block"><em>Enter the last name required attendee(s).</em></p>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
         <label>Segments</label>
           <select class="form-control dropdown" name="segment" id="segment" multiple="" placeholder="Select segments / tags for this group">
              <option value="">Select Center</option>
                <?php $counter = 1; foreach($createSegments->segments as $data){ ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $data->id; ?>"><?php echo $data->segmentName; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
           </select>
           <p class="help-block"><em>Click to select the segments or tags that this focus group pertains to.</em></p>
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-11">
           <br />
           <button type="button" name="createFocusGroup" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Create Focus Group</button>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Use css to get rid of the padding or margin?

Comment: wasn't sure what is causing it though, the panel, well, both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the well in Bootstrap 3 has a 20px margin bottom. Just set:

```
.well {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

to

```
.well {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```